# Profinite Local Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Lat $A$ be a profinite ring (that is, a directed projective limit of finite rings) which is also local of maximal ideal $m$. Then is it true that $A$ is separated for the $m$-adic topology, that is, is true that $\cap_{n=1}^\infty m^n = 0$ ?

Comment: No, finite rings aren't local. I use "also" in the sense of "as well". Did my English fail me?

Answer (score 2):

Since any quotient of a local ring is local, we see that $A$ is the proj. lim. of finite *local* rings, and that its maximal ideal is the proj. lim. of the maximal ideals of these rings.  Thus if $A_i$ is any finite quotient of $A$, we see
that $m^n$ has zero image in $A_i$ for $n$ large enough.

Thus $\bigcap_n m^n$ lies in the kernel of $A \to A_i$ for all $i$, and so vanishes.